# How to get the name and person/org of the current repo for use in .gitconfig?

Tags: git, github, git-config

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a handy tool where I can say:

`git open`

This will just open up the current github repository in your browser.  If I can get the name I could just use an alias with `https://github.com/{user or org}/{repo name}`.

Comment: What about using the URL from the remote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this bash function

For Linux:

```
function git-open-url(){
  xdg-open `git config --get remote.origin.url`
}
```

For Mac:

```
function git-open-url(){
  open `git config --get remote.origin.url`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the git-open tool. It's pretty cool, but I just wanted a little line in my `.gitconfig` so here's what I ended up doing.

```
[alias]
    open = "!open https://github.com/$(echo $(git remote get-url origin) | cut -f2 -d\":\")"
```

Works perfectly :)